# java process.waitFor() doesnt exit in a particular case

Tags: java, powershell

In the code below, i am trying to run a batch file that executes a powershell script to start a java process on a remote machine. the java process on the remote machine is a kind of daemon process that doesn't exit. I am not able to understand the behavior of the below code snippet.

```
//sample.bat -> powershell script -> remote java process(kind of daemon) 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c sample.bat");//line-1
//Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sample.bat"");//line-2
p.getOutputStream().close();
p.getInputStream().close();
p.waitFor();
p.destroy();
```

If i invoke cmd.exe(line-1) the waitfor() seems to work. i see a cmd window opening, the console output of the remote process is seen on the console. once the remote java process is up and running, the waitFor() exits.
But if i invoke the script directly(line-2), the waitfor() is held for ever and never exits. why is this so?
TIA!